# IE Browser Window goes to background when clicking any link on the page

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, requirejs

I am facing very weird issue with Internet Explorer 9 and 10. I have a web application and when I click any link of the page, the Internet explorer goes into background (background means that any other open window like chrome, file explorer, skype comes at front and IE goes background.

This is very weird and I am getting no clue how this is done.

The example of the link is like this :

```
<a class="menu_public" href="/portal/c/portal/login?p_l_id=11012">Home</a>
```

Any clues?

### UPDATE

I found the cause of this, but does not know how to tackle that

The root cause is the inclusion of require.js, here is my insert statement in html `<head>` tag.

```
<script data-main="scripts/config" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/libs/requireJS_2.1.5.js"></script>
```

When I remove this statement, the IE works fine. I need this JS inclusion, so can anybody tell me how should I resolve?

### UPDATE

I found that the `define()` call is creating this issue, I tried removing the definition one by one and found that it occurs only when I have my custom object dependencies.

So, my define() block looks like

```
define(['jquery', 
        'collection/Button', 
        'collection/Tutorial', 
        'collection/Notification', 
        'collection/Tooltip', 
        'component/Navigation', 
        'xxx/utils'], function($) {

});
```

it works perfectly fine, when I have only 'jquery' in `define()`. All other do this weird behavior.

Comment: What Javascript events are attached to the links, if any?

Comment: It does not depend on what script it has, sometimes it is a normal server request URLs, so no scripts in that manner.

Comment: Show some code.. that could help resolve your issue#

Comment: Maybe try another computer. Sounds more like a general software issue.

Comment: Ofcourse, I have tried on several computers! when did not work, seeking help here! (following standard guidelines of software development)

Comment: Tried disabling Javascript?

Comment: @FelixChristy,Instead of loading it from local machine, try loading it from CDN. See whether that makes it work.

Comment: @FelixChristy I have the same problem, any luck with you? tnx

Comment: @Spring, i added the answer!

Comment: @FelixChristy in my case it was "$body.focus().blur()"

Comment: Then avoid blurring entire body, try to blur the main class (where your content is). blurring body creates issue. refer link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the solution, it is because I had the following code somewhere in my javascript

```
$(document.activeElement).blur();
```

just change that to

```
$(document.activeElement).not('body').blur();
```

and everything else should be fine.

Have a look here http://tjvantoll.com/2013/08/30/bugs-with-document-activeelement-in-internet-explorer/